# what is wrong the syntax

Tags: python, syntax

I have been trying to construct dictionaries using comprehension, but kep getting syntax errors. where field is a list and values is a list of tuples. the editor that I am required to use for my class does not give specifics for syntax errors.

```
{f:{'lottery a': helper(f,v,'lottery a') for v in values, 'lottery b':  helper(f,v, 'lottery b') for v in values} for f in fields[1:]}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? That would be wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap `helper(f,v,'lottery a') for v in values` with something. I assume you want a list there, so:

```
{f:{'lottery a': [helper(f,v,'lottery a') for v in values], 'lottery b':  [helper(f,v, 'lottery b') for v in values]} for f in fields[1:]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to commit to comprehesions...

```
from pprint import pprint
def helper(a, b, c):
    return (a, b, c)

fields = [1, 2, 3]
values = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

a = a = {f: {c: {v: helper(f, v, c) for v in values} for c in ('lottery a', 'lottery b')} for f in fields[1:]}
pprint(a)

{2: {'lottery a': {(1, 1): (2, (1, 1), 'lottery a'),
               (2, 2): (2, (2, 2), 'lottery a'),
               (3, 3): (2, (3, 3), 'lottery a')},
 'lottery b': {(1, 1): (2, (1, 1), 'lottery b'),
               (2, 2): (2, (2, 2), 'lottery b'),
               (3, 3): (2, (3, 3), 'lottery b')}},
 3: {'lottery a': {(1, 1): (3, (1, 1), 'lottery a'),
               (2, 2): (3, (2, 2), 'lottery a'),
               (3, 3): (3, (3, 3), 'lottery a')},
 'lottery b': {(1, 1): (3, (1, 1), 'lottery b'),
               (2, 2): (3, (2, 2), 'lottery b'),
               (3, 3): (3, (3, 3), 'lottery b')}}}
```